# Ho to get K2 item to display on K2 category page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I have a task on joomla site that uses k2 to display content. So the task is as follows: i need to put javascript box with tabs and display k2 item when k2category item is pressed without reloading the page.

So the question is, how do i get the k2 item layout inside a div on k2category layout? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If I recall correctly, the items' text is available in category view. I am not sure that it is completely rendered (e.g, galleries etc.), but I think that most of it is there. You should probably dig a little bit through the code or add a breakpoint in your template to see what's available. You should probably create a sub-template for the category-array and render each item by invoking it.

Comment: Well i've compared the K2ViewItem and K2ViewItemList(this one is for category). Both of them have $this->item->itrotext, which has the full text in K2ViewItem, but in K2ViewItemList it contains only small part of text... 
The part in category view, that loads the category items list is:

  `$this->item=$item;
  echo $this->loadTemplate('item');`
inside the `<?php foreach($this->leading as $key=>$item): ?>` loop.

I wish i could get the item full content like that in category...

Comment: You can always change the K2 core.

Comment: $this->item->fulltext contains the fulltext of the K2 item.

Comment: @betweenbrain , I need fulltext in K2ViewItemList(category.php layout). When i try to echo $this->item->fulltext in there it outputs nothing. Please advise me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The only solution i found for now is to get the items directly from the database. Im not sure if this is the best way. I'm still open for any suggestions you can offer! Thanks